# Edit attributes in relation

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, editing

I have made a 1 / N union using the QGIS tool between an attribute table in CSV format and a shapefile using a common field(**N**).

The .csv attribute layer has the following field structure:

*ID - **N**- T*

1  - 1 -  T5

2 - 1  - T5

3 - 1 -  T5

and the shapefile layer the following:

***N*** - F - G

1 - F1 - G1

2 - F2 -  G2

If I load the CSV layer from PostGIS I can edit the attributes but if I load from a folder it does not allow me to edit those attributes.

Is this edition only possible by loading the CSV layer from PostGIS?

Comment: are you trying to edit the attributes after you established the relational join? in general, data loaded from PostGIS is stored in memory as a temporal layer, with no hard reference to the data in the database and thus can be edited freely (but needs to either be uploaded or saved to file). the data loaded from file stays associated to the file, you need to switch into edit mode to allow changes and save all changes explicitly to be able to alter that data permanently.

Comment: Hi. As far as I have been able to study this type of connections (Project Properties / Relationships), I have not been able to create a new layer that fixes this type of union in its attributes even importing from Postgis. With the union from the properties of the layer (shp or csv) if I could but is a union 1/1. It is true that you have to put layers in editing mode but for the moment and raising the initial situation I have not yet been able to, just using Postgis to import the layer of attributes to be joined.

Comment: Are you using the steps in the docs? there's a few ways to achieve what you are doing so some clarification on your exact method will help us solve your problem. https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#introducing-1-n-relations

Comment: Thanks for the reference. This has been revised in order to apply it to an example similar to the one in the statement of the question. The process that has been followed is as follows:
1 Project Properties / Relationships.2 Add Relationship.3 Name: Test.4 Reference layer (Daughter): data.csv.5 Reference field: N.6 Reference layer (Parent): layer.shp.7 Reference field: N.8- ID: empty
As a result for N=1 layer information:(ID-N-T)(1-1-T5)(2-1-T5)(3-1-T5),but it does not allow its edition.Only importing the data from postgis could be edited the attribute data.